# Stack Implementation with getMiddle and getAt functions

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, stack, time-complexity

I need to create data structure acting like stack (LIFO) with these functions: init(), push(Object), pop(), getMiddle(), getAt(k).
All of the fucntion except getAt() should be with complexity O(1), and getAt(k) with time complexity O(log(k)). Space Complexity should be O(n)

The problem is getAt(k) function, when k is index of k'th inserted (accoriding to inserting order) element in the stack.
I decided to go with DoublyLinkedList because then I'll can to move pointer to the middle element. I also share a code. If someone has any suggestions about how I can even get O(k) complexity or even the solution.

```
class Node {

    Node prev;
    Node next;
    Object data;
    int order; //index of inserted element

    Node(Object data, int order) {
        prev = null;
        next = null;
        this.data = data;
        this.order = order;
    }
}

public class LikeStack {

    Node head;
    Node mid;
    int size;

    //constructor
    public LikeStack() {
        this.size = 0;
        this.head = null;
        this.mid = null;
    }

    //push object to the stack and move the pointer to the middle of the stack if needed
    public void push(Object o) {
        size++;
        Node toPush = new Node(o, size);
        toPush.prev = null;
        toPush.next = head;
        if (size == 1) {
            mid = toPush;
        } else {
            head.prev = toPush;
            {
                if (size % 2 == 1) {
                    mid = mid.prev;
                }
            }
        }
        head = toPush;
    }

    //pop object from the stack and move the pointer to the middle of the stack if needed
    public Object pop() throws Exception {
        if(size<=0)
        {
            throw new Exception("The stack is empty");
        }
        size--;
        Object temp = head.data;
        head=head.next;
        if(head!=null)
        {
            head.prev=null;
        }
        if(size%2==1)
        {
            mid=mid.next;
        }
        return temp;
    }

    //just returning the middle element
    public Object getMiddle(){
        return mid.data;
    }
```

Comment: Why can't you use a map with DLL to make it O(1) ?

Comment: `getAt(k)` can be done in `log(n)` without having an additional data structure, where `n` is size of the current stack. Are you sure `log(k)` is the right requirement?

Comment: @SomeDude yes, it's question from my homework and it's log(k) requirement

Comment: @vivek_23 Id like if you could explain detailed, because I have no idea how its possible to do it in constant time with map

Comment: @sirkol123 to get O(1) you just build a map of inserted_index -> Node

Answer (score 0):

- First is to maintain an index variable, say `index` to `0`.
- When you do the `push()`, you will add the element to the map like:

> ```
>    void push(int value){
>       // your code
>       map.put(index++,your_node);
>    }
> ```

- In your `pop()`, you would do

> ```
> int pop(){
>    // your code
>    your_node.prev.next = null;
>    map.remove(index--);
> }
> ```

- So, getting the middle element will just be a lookup in the map

> ```
> int middle(){
>    // your code
>    return map.get(index / 2).value;
> }
> ```

- Getting the value at `k` will be similar to the above:

> ```
> int getKthElement(int K){
>    // your code
>    return map.get(K-1).value; // If K is above index, you can throw an exception
> }
> ```